# PyUnit: stop after first failing test?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm using the following code in my testing framework:

```
testModules = ["test_foo", "test_bar"]

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromNames(testModules)
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(sys.stdout, verbosity=2)
results = runner.run(suite)
return results.wasSuccessful()
```

Is there a way to make the reporting (`runner.run`?) abort after the first failure to prevent excessive verbosity?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Nine years after the question was asked, this is still one of the top search results for "python unit test fail early" and, as I discovered when looking at the other search results, these answers are no longer correct for more recent versions of the unittest module.

The documentation for the unittest module https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-options and https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html#command-line-options show that there is an argument, failfast=True, that can be added to unittest.main, or equivalently a command line option, -f, or --failfast, to stop the test run on the first error or failure. This option was added in version 2.7. Using that option is a lot easier than the previously-necessary workarounds suggested in the other answers.

That is, simply change your

```
unittest.main()
```

to

```
unittest.main(failfast=True)
```

Answer (score 7):

It's a feature. If you want to override this, you'll need to subclass `TestCase` and/or `TestSuite` classes and override logic in the `run()` method.

P.S.:
I think you have to subclass `unittest.TestCase` and override method `run()` in your class:

```
def run(self, result=None):
    if result is None: result = self.defaultTestResult()
    result.startTest(self)
    testMethod = getattr(self, self._testMethodName)
    try:
        try:
            self.setUp()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            raise
        except:
            result.addError(self, self._exc_info())
            return

        ok = False
        try:
            testMethod()
            ok = True
        except self.failureException:
            result.addFailure(self, self._exc_info())
            result.stop()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            raise
        except:
            result.addError(self, self._exc_info())
            result.stop()

        try:
            self.tearDown()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            raise
        except:
            result.addError(self, self._exc_info())
            ok = False
        if ok: result.addSuccess(self)
    finally:
        result.stopTest(self)
```

(I've added two `result.stop()` calls to the default `run` definition).

Then you'll have to modify all your testcases to make them subclasses of this new class, instead of `unittest.TestCase`.

***WARNING***: I didn't test this code. :)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm quite capable of that (or rather, I don't wanna put too much effort into this... ).
I was hoping there'd be an equivalent of py.test's --exitfirst option.

Comment: Well, there's no other way. Actually, unittest.py code is rather simple - easy to read and extend.

Comment: I've looked into this, and tried to override unittest.TextTestRunner.test to abort if a flag was set - but that's the entire set of tests already, so it doesn't help me...
Any pointers would be most welcome!

Comment: I've tried to describe one way to solve your problem. It is also possible to create a custom `TestSuite` subclass and override its `run()` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that - your solution worked, and it allowed me to understand enough to tweak it to be less intrusive - will post a separate reply with details (no markup in comments... ).

Answer (score 7):

Based on Eugene's guidance, I've come up with the following:

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):  
    def run(self, result=None):
        if result.failures or result.errors:
            print "aborted"
        else:
            super(TestCase, self).run(result)
```

While this works fairly well, it's a bit annoying that each individual test module has to define whether it wants to use this custom class or the default one (a command-line switch, similar to `py.test`'s `--exitfirst`, would be ideal)...

Answer (score 0):

Building on AnC's answer, this is what I'm using...

```
def aborting_run(self, result=None):
    if result.failures or result.errors:
        print "aborted"
    else:
        original_run(self, result)
original_run = unittest.TestCase.run
unittest.TestCase.run = aborting_run
```