# Is there a test watcher type interface for Python's UnitTest?

Tags: unit-testing, python-2.7

I'm coming from a `JUnit` background.  In the past I've implemented capturing screenshots upon test failure using Rules and `TestWatcher` interface in Java.  Is there something similar in Python?

http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html

```
public static class WatchmanTest {
    private static String watchedLog;

    @Rule
    public MethodRule watchman= new TestWatcher() {
            @Override
            protected void failed(Description d) {
                    watchedLog+= d + "\n";
            }

            @Override
            protected void succeeded(Description d) {
                    watchedLog+= d + " " + "success!\n";
            }
    };

    @Test
    public void fails() {
            fail();
    }

    @Test
    public void succeeds() {
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around to what I wanted to do by overriding the TestCase.run() method in my BaseTest class.

I got the clue from reason this post which talked about altering the run characteristics by overriding the run method:

[PyUnit: stop after first failing test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685424/pyunit-stop-after-first-failing-test)