# How can I stop unit test on python 2.6?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.6, python-unittest

I ran my tests by bash command

```
python src/flow.py
```

When a test fail, I want to stop running to debug

Comment: Using what, an ide? the command line debugger?

Comment: I am using command line

Comment: What is the problem excatly? You want to fix it where?

Comment: I want run tests and correct them with a clear interface. one by one

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine "run" as explained in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685424/pyunit-stop-after-first-failing-test).

They note that this has the disadvantage that "run" needs to be redefined in every class. Therefore you can create your own class and inherit from it. Put this in its own module.

```
class TestCaseStopFirstFail(unittest.TestCase):
    def run():
        ...
```

Import the module. Then use this to define all of your tests:

```
class myTestClass(TestCaseStopFirstFail):
    ...
```